# ABAP OPEN DATASET and TRANSFER

Tags: abap

I am trying to create a new file with the information that i will extract from my BD.

```
CONCATENATE cdf ndf
INTO cdf.

 OPEN DATASET cdf for APPENDING IN LEGACY TEXT MODE WITH SMART LINEFEED.
  IF sy-subrc = 0.
      TRANSFER wa_es_tabt TO ndf.
      CLOSE DATASET cdf.
   ENDIF.
```

`CDF` = the path of my file with the name that the user will put

`NDF` = the name the user will put

`wa_es_tabt` = db information that I intend to save as txt.

but the `sy-subrc` is always 8, file not open... why?

thanks...

Comment: What is the contents of `cdf` when trying to open the file? What is the operating system of the application server(s)?

Answer (score 0):

I did solve my problem this is the example of my program to create an save an txt file in ABAP.

```
FORM g_fich  TABLES   dt_es_tab STRUCTURE es_tabd
             USING    str       TYPE string
                      str1      TYPE string.

  CONCATENATE cdf ndf '.txt'
  INTO str.
  CONCATENATE 'Parceiro' 'Conta Contrato' 'Conttrato' 'Nome' 'Morada'
  INTO str1
  SEPARATED BY space.

  OPEN DATASET str FOR APPENDING IN TEXT MODE ENCODING DEFAULT WITH SMART LINEFEED .

  IF sy-subrc = 0.
    LOOP AT dt_es_tab INTO wa_es_tabt.

      IF cont = 0.
        TRANSFER str1 TO str.
        cont = 2.
      ENDIF.

      TRANSFER wa_es_tabt TO str.
    ENDLOOP.
  ENDIF.

  CLOSE DATASET str.

ENDFORM.                    " G_FIC
```

`CDF` = the path of my file with the name that the user will put

`NDF` = the name the user will put

`wa_es_tabt` = data from BD that I intend to save as txt.

the problem with the old one was that i was intend to create a new file without an extension, like  ".txt", and 
I was trying to open an file whit just hes name.

thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Well... That's not the point. You simple have to use the identical destination in both `OPEN DATASET` and `TRANSFER` statement.

eg:

```
OPEN DATASET abc FOR OUTPUT/APPENDING.
TRANSFER <whatever_you_want> TO abc.
```

In your first example you had the OPEN DATASET for `cdf` but the transfer to `ndf` which wasn't open for transfer at all.

The latter example only works because you use both times the destination variable `str` for both `OPEN DATASET` and `TRANSFER`.